# how to build a data frame store three matrix in r?

Tags: r

I have three matrix both have form

```
matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3)
```

I want to store it into a data frame

which has
like[[1]]
matrix 1
[[2]]
matrix2
[[3]]
matrix3

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to store them in a list? `result <- list(mat1, mat2, mat3)` ?

Comment: list is good , if you can turn it into mcmclist type it is very good. data frame is also good.Thanks

Comment: What is `mcmclist` ? I am not sure if I understand what kind of output you are looking for. Can you share 3 example matrix and show it's expected output?

Comment: it is a mcmclist type , which I want to plot it use trace.plot for the mcmc.https://rdrr.io/cran/coda/man/mcmc.list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
tmp <- list(mat1, mat2, mat3)
df <- structure(list(matvar = tmp), row.names = c(NA, -length(tmp)), class = "data.frame")
```

`tmp` looks like this

```
> tmp
[[1]]
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.3621874 -0.6561387 -0.4677576
[2,] -0.4151266 -1.6263417  0.2591169
[3,] -1.2929423  0.1605372 -0.3765355

[[2]]
          [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
[1,] -1.295392 -0.32709544 -0.05570772
[2,]  2.006265  0.09771237 -0.63585629
[3,]  1.238755  0.82780041 -1.12397580

[[3]]
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -2.3938130 -0.1281216  0.8533604
[2,]  0.5994161 -1.2863790  0.7520429
[3,]  2.3972049  0.4912612 -1.6504007
```

`df` looks like this

```
> df
                                                                                                            myvar
1        -1.3621874, -0.4151266, -1.2929423, -0.6561387, -1.6263417, 0.1605372, -0.4677576, 0.2591169, -0.3765355
2 -1.29539220, 2.00626468, 1.23875540, -0.32709544, 0.09771237, 0.82780041, -0.05570772, -0.63585629, -1.12397580
3           -2.3938130, 0.5994161, 2.3972049, -0.1281216, -1.2863790, 0.4912612, 0.8533604, 0.7520429, -1.6504007

> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ myvar:List of 3
  ..$ : num [1:3, 1:3] -1.362 -0.415 -1.293 -0.656 -1.626 ...
  ..$ : num [1:3, 1:3] -1.2954 2.0063 1.2388 -0.3271 0.0977 ...
  ..$ : num [1:3, 1:3] -2.394 0.599 2.397 -0.128 -1.286 ...
```

---

**Update**

There is a function called `as.mcmc` and another one called `as.mcmc.list` in that `coda` package. Why don't you just use these two functions to create the list of matrices you want? Something like this

```
library(coda)

as.mcmc.list(lapply(list(mat1, mat2, mat3), as.mcmc))
```

Output

```
[[1]]
Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) output:
Start = 1 
End = 3 
Thinning interval = 1 
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.2969923 -0.7310411  0.4196365
[2,] 1.2409177  1.1632943 -0.5577441
[3,] 0.8150555  0.7716736  0.3789444

[[2]]
Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) output:
Start = 1 
End = 3 
Thinning interval = 1 
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 1.9651037  0.3937134 0.04957419
[2,] 0.4323131  1.3044387 0.52566943
[3,] 0.5666462 -0.1546477 2.61252474

[[3]]
Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) output:
Start = 1 
End = 3 
Thinning interval = 1 
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.75325880 -1.2907239 -1.9141196
[2,] -1.42620147 -0.1280831 -0.5911452
[3,] -0.06083325 -1.3159765 -1.1363787

attr(,"class")
[1] "mcmc.list"
```

Comment: thank you sir. do you know how to turn this like a mcmclist object which can input for the trace.plot function? thanks

Comment: I try to use the first one into the trace.plot function. It said  argument of length 0